# How to find your own interest categories on Google?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to be able to find out a little bit more about the Interests section on Google Analytics by finding out what it registers my own interests as, however, I'm not sure how one would go about doing this.

How can someone determine what Google considers to be their "interest" categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When signed into Google, you can find your *Interests* listed under Google's Ads Settings here: https://www.google.com/settings/ads